# Aggregate Totals From Arrays

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a problem grouping data with MongoDb.

I've a stok of items with some in/out movements and i want to compute a summary of items with amount of movements but the movements are not computed correctly.

Here is my sample data, a small list with two stocks and some movements....

```
/* 1 */
{
    "TemplateName" : "SAALottoStagionatura",
    "idStock" : 31789,
    "idWarehouse" : 191,
    "StockCode" : "71529902",   
    "Marks" : [ 
        {
            "idMark" : 20145,
            "idWarehouse" : 191,
            "idStock" : 31789,
            "ProgressivoDocumento" : 486,
            "Year" : 2016,
            "RefDate" : ISODate("2016-03-28T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "MarkedItems" : 72
        }, 
        {
            "idMark" : 20156,
            "idWarehouse" : 191,
            "idStock" : 31789,
            "ProgressivoDocumento" : 497,
            "Year" : 2016,
            "RefDate" : ISODate("2016-03-30T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "MarkedItems" : 144
        }, 
        {
            "idMark" : 23424,
            "idWarehouse" : 191,
            "idStock" : 31789,
            "ProgressivoDocumento" : 840,
            "Year" : 2016,
            "RefDate" : ISODate("2016-06-12T22:00:00.000Z"),
            "MarkedItems" : 3
        }
    ],
    "Details" : [ 
        {
            "idLSDetail" : 42781,
            "idStock" : 31789,
            "idStockOrig" : 54502,
            "StockCode" : "71529902",
            "Items" : 4532
        }
    ],   
    "MovementsOut" : [ 
        {
            "idMovementDetail" : 633,
            "idMovement" : 511,
            "MovedItems" : 3528 ,
            "idStockOrig" : null,
            "idStock" : 31789
        }
    ],
    "MovementsIn" : [ 
        {
            "idMovementDetail" : 715,
            "idMovement" : 570,
            "MovedItems" : 3528,
            "idStockOrig" : null,
            "idStock" : 33678
        }
    ]
}


/* 2 */
{
    "TemplateName" : "SAALottoStagionatura",
    "idStock" : 33678,
    "idWarehouse" : 190,
    "StockCode" : "71529902",
    "Marks" : [],
    "Details" : [ 
        {
            "idLSDetail" : 45206,
            "idStock" : 33678,
            "idStockOrig" : 56684,
            "StockCode" : "71529902",
            "Items" : 3528 

        }
    ],
   "MovementsOut" : [ 
        {
           "idMovementDetail" : 715,
            "idMovement" : 570,
            "MovedItems" : 3528,
            "idStockOrig" : null,
            "idStock" : 33678
        }
    ],
    "TrasferimentiInEntrata" : []
}
```

and in my query i try to group the movements

```
db.getCollection('Test')
.aggregate(
 [
      {$match: {"idWarehouse": 191, StockCode: "71529902" } }, 
      {$unwind: "$Details"}, 
      {$unwind: "$Marks"},       
      {$unwind: "$MovementsIn"},     
      {$unwind: "$MovementsOut"},     
       {
        $group : {
           _id : {  
               StockCode: "$idStock",
               StockCode: "$StockCode" 
               },

           tot: { $sum: "$Details.Items" },
           cer: { $sum: "$Marks.MarkedItems" },
           in: { $sum: "$MovementsIn.MovedItems" },
           out: { $sum: "$MovementsOut.MovedItems" }   
        }
      } 
   ]
)
```

My expectation should be this

```
{
    "_id" : {
        "StockCode" : "71529902"
    },
    "tot" : 13596,
    "cer" : 219,
    "in" : 3528,
    "out" : 7056
}
```

however i always get the full sum of the movement (10584) in both in and out. Where am i wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually in any modern MongoDB release since 3.2 you simply use the "double barelled" invocation of [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/), and no [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) at all:

```
db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "StockCode": "$StockCode"
    },
    "tot": { "$sum": { "$sum": "$Details.Items" } },
    "cer": { "$sum": { "$sum": "$Marks.MarkedItems" } },
    "in": { "$sum": { "$sum": "$MovementsIn.MovedItems" } },
    "out": { "$sum": { "$sum": "$MovementsOut.MovedItems" } }
  }}
])
```

This is because as of that version when you notate to an element in an array such as `"$Details.Items"` the projected result is an "array of values" as found at the specified path. The second addition is that [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) also "sums arrays", so it's invoked in the group to [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) the array content and then [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) as an "accumulator" between documents.

Returns the result when run against the two documents in your question:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "StockCode" : "71529902"
    },
    "tot" : 8060.0,
    "cer" : 219.0,
    "in" : 3528.0,
    "out" : 7056.0
}
```

---

In Earlier versions such as MongoDB 2.6 you could avoid the "cartesian product" which is the result of [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on multiple arrays by combining the arrays into one, possibly using [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) if the identifiers and values are actually unique:

```
db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "StockCode": 1,
    "combined": { 
      "$setUnion": [
        { "$map": {
          "input": { "$ifNull": [ "$Details", [] ] },
          "as": "el",
          "in": { "id": "$idLSDetail", "k": "Details", "v": "$$el.Items" }
        }},
        { "$map": {
          "input": { "$ifNull": [ "$Marks", [] ] },
          "as": "el",
          "in": { "id": "$idMark", "k": "Marks", "v": "$$el.MarkedItems" }
        }},
        { "$map": {
          "input": { "$ifNull": [ "$MovementsIn", [] ] },
          "as": "el",
          "in": { "id": "$idMovementDetail", "k": "MoveIn", "v": "$$el.MovedItems" }
        }},  
        { "$map": {
          "input": { "$ifNull": [ "$MovementsOut", [] ] },
          "as": "el",
          "in": { "id": "$idMovementDetail", "k": "MoveOut", "v": "$$el.MovedItems" }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$combined" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "StockCode": "$StockCode" 
    },
    "tot": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$combined.k", "Details" ] },
          "then": "$combined.v",
          "else": 0  
        }  
      }  
    },
    "cer": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$combined.k", "Marks" ] },
          "then": "$combined.v",
          "else": 0  
        }  
      }  
    },
    "in": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$combined.k", "MoveIn" ] },
          "then": "$combined.v",
          "else": 0  
        }  
      }  
    },
    "out": {
      "$sum": {
        "$cond": {
          "if": { "$eq": [ "$combined.k", "MoveOut" ] },
          "then": "$combined.v",
          "else": 0  
        }  
      }  
    }
  }}
])
```

And in older versions or indeed where "uniqueness" is not possible, you instead [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) each array separately and then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/), and repeat the process until the arrays are "reduced". Then you can `$group` as a final across documents.

But like above, you need to take care because not all documents have all arrays, and this needs to be handled. In the above sample we can just provide an "empty" array instead of `null` ( in the initial `$sum` does not care ). But once you use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on each individually you come into problems if there is nothing there or empty:

```
 db.getCollection('Test').aggregate([
  { "$project": {
     "StockCode": 1,
     "Details": { 
       "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [{ "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$Details", [] ] } }, 0] },
          [null],
          "$Details"
        ] 
     },
     "Marks": { 
       "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [{ "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$Marks", [] ] } }, 0] },
          [null],
          "$Marks"
        ] 
     },
     "MovementsIn": { 
       "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [{ "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$MovementsIn", [] ] } }, 0] },
          [null],
          "$MovementsIn"
        ] 
     },
     "MovementsOut": { 
       "$cond": [
          { "$eq": [{ "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$MovementsOut", [] ] } }, 0] },
          [null],
          "$MovementsOut"
        ] 
     }
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$Details" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "StockCode": { "$first": "$StockCode" },
    "tot": { "$sum": "$Details.Items" },
    "Marks": { "$first": "$Marks" },
    "MovementsIn": { "$first": "$MovementsIn" },
    "MovementsOut": { "$first": "$MovementsOut" }    
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$Marks" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "StockCode": { "$first": "$StockCode" },
    "tot": { "$first": "$tot" },
    "cer": { "$sum": "$Marks.MarkedItems" },
    "MovementsIn": { "$first": "$MovementsIn" },
    "MovementsOut": { "$first": "$MovementsOut" }    
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$MovementsIn" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "StockCode": { "$first": "$StockCode" },
    "tot": { "$first": "$tot" },
    "cer": { "$first": "$cer" },
    "in": { "$sum": "$MovementsIn.MovedItems" },
    "MovementsOut": { "$first": "$MovementsOut" }    
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$MovementsOut" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "StockCode": { "$first": "$StockCode" },
    "tot": { "$first": "$tot" },
    "cer": { "$first": "$cer" },
    "in": { "$first": "$in" },
    "out": { "$sum": "$MovementsOut.MovedItems" }    
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": {
      "StockCode": "$StockCode",
    },
    "tot": { "$sum": "$tot" },
    "cer": { "$sum": "$cer" },
    "in": { "$sum": "$in" },
    "out": { "$sum": "$out" }
  }}
])
```

So the tests there need [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) to work out if the array needs to be replaced or not.

Comment: Extremely clear and complete answer. Thank you so much!